# Bootstrap tabs - Typeerror .tab is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to programatically change tabs as below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" >Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" >Step 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div id="step1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    </div>
    <div id="step2" class="tab-pane fade">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS(upon certain condition):

```
$('a[href="#step2"]').tab('show');
```

This does not work and I get the error: TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function

Any ideas?

EDIT:

To be sure, I also included the following in my _Layout file as per bootstrap website:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Have you loaded bootstrap JS file

Answer (score 2):

Which browswer are you using? the integrity attribute doesn't seem to be fully integrated yet ([see the mozilla compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity#Browser_compatibility))

I tried this code without cdn link and worked just fine. on the other hand, with the integrity attribute, i got the same error as you at first, but upon reload it worked (tried on chrome 49 and firefox 45.0.2)

Comment: Have you tried with your own version of bootstrap, just in case?  Otherwise since it's working as such for me i guess the error would be elsewhere in your code, can you provide the condition of the$('a[href="#step2"]').tab('show');  ?